# UIActivityViewController display is scrolled in last iOS11 GM on iPhone7Plus

Tags: scroll, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios11

Since the last release of iOS11 (GM version), the activity view is displayed scrolled to the top, with a spring resistance preventing the user to 'unscroll' it.
Previous version of iOS 11 (beta version) never suffered from this, nor iOS 10.

Also, one can see a blank margin at the bottom plus the fact that the preview image is not fetched/displayed right in the Website preview.

Here is the code. Any idea?

```
   let textToShare = "\(message) (\(share))"


    let objectsToShare : [Any] = [textToShare, url]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare as [AnyObject], applicationActivities: nil)

    // New Excluded Activities Code
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [.airDrop, .addToReadingList]

    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {
        (activityType: UIActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error? ) -> Void in

        _completed(completed)
    }
```

[image: screenshit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It’s only Twitter app itself that had to be updated for iOS11 (as in iOS11, there is no longer centralized system, sharing is handled by apps such as Facebook or Twitter themselves).